# GET problem in WordPress

Tags: php, functions

I have a strange problem. Any form using GET redirects back to the page not sending the variables. POST does work. I thought it might be an issue with the .htaccess but I deleted it and had WordPress recreate it. No success. I have turned off all plugins. No success.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain GET and POST calls that WordPress breaks. Such as title, name....If you are using those variables, I would change the name of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify: Is it that when you have submitted a GET form, you end up at it's 'action' URL with the GET variables applied to the url (form-destination?name=barb&job=teller) -- And these are not present in the $_GET PHP super global?

Or is it that upon form submission, you are redirected back to the originating page or the value of the 'action' form parameter with the GET parameters removed from the query string?

Wordpress will act on any query variable in _GET, so it's entirely possible that you're feeding it a query variable that results in a redirect or in no results. Be careful of how you name your GET variables. Using POST is generally safer to ensure that Wordpress does not interfere with your input variables. Try to use GET only when need the resulting pages to be link-able.

The latter might be caused by a canonical rewrite.

Comment: This one: Or is it that upon form submission, you are redirected back to the originating page or the value of the 'action' form parameter with the GET parameters removed from the query string? Besides a script I wrote, I also have the plugin Event Espresso and it fails when clicking on a Get call. I apologize for not explaining this well.

Comment: Do you know the name of the parameters that are being added to the query string, and then subsequently lost in the redirect?